# How to use Html.EncodedActionLink with area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use the code given below

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink("Edit", "UpdateBlog", "Blog", new { id = item.BlogID }, null)
```

On click on above mention link url show

> localhost/Blog/UpdateBlog?q=+kBlw5MHdHA=

but i want to show link given below

> localhost/Writer/Blog/UpdateBlog?q=+kBlw5MHdHA=  (where Writer is
> Area)

How to rout Area with `@html.EncodedActionLink`

Comment: Where is `EncodedActionLink()` coming from?

Comment: asp.net mvc c# use @html.EncodedActionLink()

Comment: @html.encodedactionlink() work fine with controller but not working within area controller

Comment: Not seeing `EncodedActionLink()` anywhere in the asp.net mvc documentation, can you post a link please?

Comment: How to specify an area name in an @Html.EncodedActionLink ?